# How to detecting flat objects on a flat background in point cloud

Tags: pattern-matching, neural-network, point-cloud-library, ransac

I have a point cloud scene where a "card" is placed on a table top. It could be a normal business card or a bank card. How do I detect the presence or absence of a card in a scene? If a card is present, what are the set of points that constitute the boundary of the card?

I am using the Planar Segmentation and able to cluster out the "table top" completely.

The Point Cloud is located at http://pastebin.com/bqdjgdgc (PCD format).

Comment: A flat object on a flat surface? That does not sound like a problem that should (or even can) be solved in 3D. Instead, use a 2D (RGB) camera and go from there.

Comment: This is a small part in a rather bigger system. I figured out that this can be done by efficient combination of RGB Region Growing along with other heuristics to separate background from card.